# Pandas equivalent to R 'MAX_VALUE'

Tags: r, python-3.x, pandas

I am translating R code to Python using Pandas and I have been able to find Pandas equivalent to all R actions, but now I got this R code:

```
dtfr %>% mutate(a_column = ifelse(a_column == "INFINITY", MAX_VALUE, a_column))
```

This is my Pandas equivalent:

```
dtfr['a_column'] = np.where(dtfr['a_column'] == 'INFINITY', MAX_VALUE, dtfr['a_column'])
```

I have been looking for an equivalent to R `MAX_VALUE` in Pandas, but I haven't found how to replicate it.

Comment: Can you give an example of what it would do in R?

Comment: What is "R 'MAX_VALUE'" ? Is it a value defined by you, is it a value from `.Machine`, or ...? Also (as Joe noted in their now deleted answer), as `"INFINITY"` is a character then even if `MAX_VALUE` is a numeric it will be coerced to character as a data.frame columns can not have hold both numeric and character classes. I would be good to add a **small** example to show what your R code is doing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is np.inf: https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/constants.html#numpy.inf

It is used in pandas to represent infinity (just as np.nan is used to represent "missing values".